How to apply k/q point symmetries in Brillioun Zone on transmission function of near field radiation heat transfer
Basically, I want to find out the near field radiation transmission function between two graphene, set at Temperature(T1) and Temperature(T2). As you can see in the figure d is the separation distance between two sheets.

The transmission function (S(omega)) is written in the paper (https://journals.aps.org/prapplied/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevApplied.14.024080) in equation (5) as follows, where,  "epsilon(q)" is the dielectric function of the graphene at temperature T1 ( and T2) and "Im" means imaginary part and "q" is the momentum wave vector in the reciprocal space (the so called q points in DFT)
$S(\omega )=\int{\frac{{{d}^{2}}\mathbf{q}}{{{(2\pi )}^{2}}}}\frac{4{{e}^{-2|\mathbf{q}|d}}\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}(q))\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}(q))}{|1-{{e}^{-2qd}}[({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}(q))-1][({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}(q))-1]{{|}^{2}}}$
They replaced the integral of the Eq. with a sum of parallel wave vectors in the first Brillouin zone.
I believe that they used the following relation (though they have not mentioned the conversion) to convert the integral to finite summation,
$\frac{A}{{{(2\pi )}^{2}}}\int_{BZ}{f(\mathbf{q}){{d}^{2}}\mathbf{q}}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}{{{w}_{i}}f(}{{\mathbf{q}}_{i}})$
where A is the area of the unit cell (Hexagonal for graphene) and w is the weight of corresponding q points and N is the total number of q points in the 1st BZ. so now, let's say in our case,
$f(\mathbf{q})=\frac{4{{e}^{-2|\mathbf{q}|d}}\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}(q))\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}(q))}{|1-{{e}^{-2|\mathbf{q}|d}}[({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}(q))-1][({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}(q))-1]{{|}^{2}}}$
then the equation of transmission becomes:
$S(\omega )=\int{\frac{{{d}^{2}}\mathbf{q}}{{{(2\pi )}^{2}}}}f(\mathbf{q})=\frac{1}{A}\sum\limits_{\mathbf{q}\in 1BZ}{{{w}_{\mathbf{q}}}f(\mathbf{q})}=\frac{1}{A}\sum\limits_{\mathbf{q}\in 1BZ}{{{w}_{\mathbf{q}}}\frac{4{{e}^{-2|\mathbf{q}|d}}\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}(q))\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}(q))}{|1-{{e}^{-2|\mathbf{q}|d}}[({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}(q))-1][({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}(q))-1]{{|}^{2}}}}$
If we don't apply symmetries on q points in the BZ, then each q point has a weight of 1/N, N is the total number of q points (as summation of weight of q points must be 1)
${{w}_{\mathbf{q}}}=\frac{1}{N}$
Finally, the following equation (mentioned as equation no 9) they have used in their paper.
$S(\omega )=\frac{1}{NA}\sum\limits_{\mathbf{q}\in 1BZ}{\frac{4{{e}^{-2|\mathbf{q}|d}}\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}(\mathbf{q}))\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}(\mathbf{q}))}{|1-{{e}^{-2|\mathbf{q}|d}}[({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}(q))-1][({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}(q))-1]{{|}^{2}}}}$
They mentioned that they have used 8100 (90 90 1) k points in DFT simulation (using quantum espresso). And to find out the q dependent dielectric function, they have used yambo.  In yambo, the dielectric function is printed at the same number k points one uses in non-self-consistent field (nscf) calculation (and the coordinates of q points in yambo are the same as the k points in nscf DFT). That means, it will generate 8100 q dependent dielectric functions. That also means, if we use the above S(omega) (no symmetries), we have to generate 8100 k points, equivalently, 8100 q points dielectric function and each of the q point weights would be 1/8100, which I have found very cumbersome and computationally very expensive.
so I decided I will apply symmetries on k points while running nscf calculation and QE prints the weight of each k points in the output. I have seen that if I apply symmetries, it generates 721 q points in IBZ (out of 8100). However, to apply the symmetries on k points, I need to change the equation and here I am showing what I have done.
so, our transmission equation was:
$S(\omega )=\frac{1}{A}\sum\limits_{\mathbf{q}\in 1BZ}{{{w}_{\mathbf{q}}}\frac{4{{e}^{-2|\mathbf{q}|d}}\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}(\mathbf{q}))\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}(\mathbf{q}))}{|1-{{e}^{-2|\mathbf{q}|d}}[({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}(\mathbf{q}))-1][({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}(\mathbf{q}))-1]{{|}^{2}}}}$
This time the weight(w_q) is not simply 1/8100. As in yambo/QE, the weight of each q point is printed, and I have used the weight in the above equation. And the equation I used in my code as follows:
$\begin{align}
  & S(\omega )=\frac{1}{A}({{w}_{{{\mathbf{q}}_{1}}}}\frac{4{{e}^{-2|{{\mathbf{q}}_{1}}|d}}\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}({{\mathbf{q}}_{1}}))\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}({{\mathbf{q}}_{1}}))}{|1-{{e}^{-2|{{\mathbf{q}}_{1}}|d}}[({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}({{\mathbf{q}}_{1}}))-1][({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}({{\mathbf{q}}_{1}}))-1]{{|}^{2}}}+{{w}_{{{\mathbf{q}}_{2}}}}\frac{4{{e}^{-2|{{\mathbf{q}}_{2}}|d}}\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}({{\mathbf{q}}_{2}}))\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}({{\mathbf{q}}_{2}}))}{|1-{{e}^{-2|{{\mathbf{q}}_{2}}|d}}[({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}({{\mathbf{q}}_{2}}))-1][({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}({{\mathbf{q}}_{2}}))-1]{{|}^{2}}} \\ 
 & +{{w}_{{{\mathbf{q}}_{3}}}}\frac{4{{e}^{-2|{{\mathbf{q}}_{3}}|d}}\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}({{\mathbf{q}}_{3}}))\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}({{\mathbf{q}}_{3}}))}{|1-{{e}^{-2|{{\mathbf{q}}_{3}}|d}}[({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}({{\mathbf{q}}_{3}}))-1][({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}({{\mathbf{q}}_{3}}))-1]{{|}^{2}}}+.........+{{w}_{{{\mathbf{q}}_{N}}}}\frac{4{{e}^{-2|{{\mathbf{q}}_{N}}|d}}\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}({{\mathbf{q}}_{N}}))\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}({{\mathbf{q}}_{N}}))}{|1-{{e}^{-2|{{\mathbf{q}}_{1}}|d}}[({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}({{\mathbf{q}}_{N}}))-1][({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}({{\mathbf{q}}_{N}}))-1]{{|}^{2}}}) \\ 
\end{align}$
But after applying the above formulae, when I compare my result with the paper, I have seen the result is not matched completely.

so, I am confused about where I might make mistakes. Is the above equation (related k/q point symmetries) OK to you? Also, another thing in my mind which is:
$S(\omega )=\frac{1}{A}\sum\limits_{\mathbf{q}\in 1BZ}{{{w}_{\mathbf{q}}}\frac{4{{e}^{-2{{w}_{\mathbf{q}}}|\mathbf{q}|d}}{{w}_{\mathbf{q}}}\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}(\mathbf{q})){{w}_{\mathbf{q}}}\operatorname{Im}({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}(\mathbf{q}))}{|1-{{e}^{-2{{w}_{\mathbf{q}}}|\mathbf{q}|d}}[{{w}_{\mathbf{q}}}({{\varepsilon }_{1}}^{-1}(\mathbf{q}))-1][{{w}_{\mathbf{q}}}({{\varepsilon }_{2}}^{-1}(\mathbf{q}))-1]{{|}^{2}}}}$
Here, as you can see, I have multiplied the weight factor with each of the q dependent terms (function). However, I still couldn't get fruitful results (I don't understand which one is correct).
Do anyone has any suggestions that I could follow?
